Search for specific node in Firebase
I have path called pairs in firebase that stores child nodes like this.
pairs has childname like form of foreign keys connection in relational databases between users table and bracelets table and storing like (braceletid-userid)
pairs{
  braceletid-userid{
    braceletname:namevalue,
    braceletid:braceletidvalue,
    userid:useridvalue
  }
  ....
}

I want to retrive all childs that have specific userid like 1234 value and get braceletid and braceletname values.
here is the complete JSON database
{
  "bracelets": {
    "12345": {
      "braceletID": 12345,
      "braceletName": "m1",
      "latitude": 21.42,
      "longitude": 22.827237
    },
    "4545": {
      "braceletID": 4545,
      "braceletName": "m3",
      "latitude": 21.421189,
      "longitude": 22.827237
    }
  },
  "pairs": {
    "12345-xfdftt56454": {
      "braceletID": "12345",
      "braceletName": "m1",
      "userId": "xfdftt56454"
    },
    "4545-5W2lRzan1": {
      "braceletID": "4545",
      "braceletName": "m3",
      "userId": "5W2lRzan1"
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "xfdftt56454": {
      "name": "h",
      "phone": "0555",
      "uid": "xfdftt56454"
    },
    "5W2lRzan1": {
      "name": "m",
      "phone": "013242",
      "uid": "5W2lRzan1"
    }
  }
}

I have recyclerview list in android and I want to populate it with braceletnames that have specific userid.
I need this code in Kotlin.

Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your Firebase Console.

I added JSON format

Thanks for adding the database schema. Did Pinankh's answer help you solve the problem?
